# Six votes recommending deletion, but not deleted

Tags: discussion, bug, answers, review-queues, deletion

[This answer](//english.stackexchange.com/q/370490/26083#370500) to [Is there any word for “killing someone by conspiracy”?](//english.stackexchange.com/q/370490/26083)
got into [the Low Quality Review queue](//english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/219646),
where it got six “Recommend Deletion” votes (and no others)
and the review is labeled as completed
(at 2017-01-27 15:29:15Z — 10 hours ago). 
It currently looks like this:

> Review completed 10 hours ago:
>   [Cascabel](//english.stackexchange.com/users/160305/cascabel) reviewed this 10 hours ago: **Recommend Deletion**
>   [Wrzlprmft](//english.stackexchange.com/users/42471/wrzlprmft) reviewed this 10 hours ago: **Recommend Deletion**
>   [Spagirl](//english.stackexchange.com/users/168678/spagirl) reviewed this 12 hours ago: **Recommend Deletion**
>   [NVZ](//english.stackexchange.com/users/50044/nvz) reviewed this 14 hours ago: **Recommend Deletion**
>   [Scott](//english.stackexchange.com/users/26083/scott) reviewed this 19 hours ago: **Recommend Deletion**
>   [Nathaniel](//english.stackexchange.com/users/53711/nathaniel) reviewed this 20 hours ago: **Recommend Deletion**

And yet the answer is not deleted. 
(Neither the [revision history](//english.stackexchange.com/posts/370500/revisions) nor the [timeline](//english.stackexchange.com/posts/370500/timeline)
indicates that it was deleted and undeleted.) 
Why is this answer still extant? 
Is it just because none of the six voters
has [delete privilege (≥ 20K rep)](//english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)? 
Is it because the answer got three upvotes (and one downvote)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because it had a net positive score at the time that six recommends were racked up.

There's a notice on it. Eventually if the user doesn't return pretty soon and fix it up, it will probably be deleted, either by three 20k users once it's negative, or by a moderator.

Comment: Thanks. I've recommended deletion on hundreds of answers, and I've never seen that before.